# live streaming using MediaLibDemos3x

Tags: ios, streaming, live

Can I live stream the video (codec: H264) playing on ipad from an external source instead of ipad camera using MediaLibDemos3x?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - see RTMPPhotoPublisher demo sample: https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos3x